# Approximate shape from contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I have used OpenCV to find contours of a binarized image and wonder how can we approximate the shape of contours such as circle, square or irregular so that i can categorize the contours. Thus, is there any way to do this in OpenCV??

EDIT: Besides, instead of fitting a circle surrounding the contour, can we fit a circle into a contour in OpenCV??

Comment: I think you want `cv::approxPolyDP`. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html has info on it and a few other approximations (like bounding box, circles, and ellipsoids).

Comment: @TimothyMurphy, hi, thanks but i have already included the bounding box as well as circle to estimate the shape but with that estimation, irregular shape does fit in as well.

Comment: [Here](http://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) you can find a few geometric measures to classifiy shapes.

Comment: @Miki, hi, thanks a lot, it seems to be of what i want, will try it later and see how it fares as i have extremely irregular shape in my image